# The [fire-tv] tag was replaced by new [amazon-fire-tv] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

I'm curious why [fire-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fire-tv) was replaced (broke my search) rather than renaming or creating a synonym for the tag.

[amazon-fire-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-tv) tag has a much less accurate description, and there doesn't appear to be any record on the questions of them being re-tagged.

I'm not arguing that the new tag creates a more descriptive name, just curious to learn more about the process and the decisions that would have lead to the creation of a new, less well-described tag.

Comment: what do you mean by "less well-described?"  Do you mean the tag wiki is less descriptive?

Comment: There was no process here, user @rekire retagged all the [fire-tv] tags 21 hours ago.  The system then probably destroyed the tag when no questions were left.  This is not the right way to go about it afaik, burninations like this ought to be proposed first.  But the volume was low so its a bit of a toss-up.  You can propose a tag synonym.

Comment: Put an accurate tag wiki description in your question, and someone with sufficient reputation will edit it in.  I've added the synonym.

Comment: thanks Robert, synonym will help find things :) psubee2003 just to clarify... the new tag originally had a less descriptive wiki (mis-characterized the product) so I'd suggested an edit (since accepted). Finally Hans ... thanks for the explanation, makes sense now